# The “.” it is written without me pressing it 

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I don't know why it happens but the (.) is written in any application without me doing something

I do not think it is my keyboard because in windows this did not happen to me and with an application that shows me on the screen the keys that I operate the (.) button does not appear as if it were activated

.................................................. .................................................. .......................................................

there an example stop writing for a few seconds

Comment: Does this happen if you use that keyboard with a different physical computer? Does this happen if you use a different physical keyboard with this computer? does this happen if you disconnect the keyboard entirely?

Comment: if I disable the keyboard it stops happening but in windows this does not happen to me

Comment: Please test all three scenarios and provide a clear answer to each. These are essential fact-finding questions in this type of situation

Comment: Does this happen if you use that keyboard with a different physical computer?

It's a laptop I can't get it out XD


Does this happen if you use a different physical keyboard with this computer?


If I deactivate the keyboard from the terminal and connect a USB keyboard it does not happen



does this happen if you disconnect the keyboard entirely?


no